# Disable cells in NSArray UITableView

Tags: uitableview, nsarray

I'm loading a tableview and would like to grey out object 2 and objet 4 and make them disabled to user interaction.

In .h I have

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *list;
```

and .m:

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        self.list = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Object 1", @"Object 2", @"Object 3", @"Object 4", @"Object 5", nil];


    }
```

and

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    cell.textLabel.text = [list objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];


    return cell;
}
```

I've tried getting the object using

object = [self.list objectAtIndex: 2] to get Object 2 but it doesn't do anything.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `textLabel` a `UILabel` or a `UITextField`? The naming leaves me to wonder. Assuming it's a `UILabel` and you want to prevent interaction with the cell (and controls in it) you could do the following.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    cell.textLabel.text = [list objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];


    if (indexPath.row == 1 || indexPath.row == 3) {
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    } else {
        cell.userInteractionEnable = YES;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Or are you just trying to prevent users from selecting the cell? In which case you should probably consider overriding `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` in the `UITableViewDelegate`.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == 1 || indexPath.row == 3) {
        return nil;
    return indexPath;
}
```